# Using jQuery .find() with multiple conditions at the same time?

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I know that there are other ways of grabbing radio button values, but I want to know how to do this with .find().

I only want to log the value of the selected radio button, so it requires finding by two conditions at the same time:

The button with `name=area`

The button with `selected=selected`

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input class="track-order-change" type="radio" name="area" id="area1" value="area1" checked="checked">
    Area 1
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input class="track-order-change" type="radio" name="area" id="area2" value="area2">
    Area 2
  </label>
</div>
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input class="track-order-change" type="radio" name="area" id="area3" value="area3">
    Area 3
  </label>
</div>
```

When anything with the class `track-order-change` changes, it will run the function UpdateOrderSubmission.

```
$('.track-order-change').on('change', function() { updateOrderSubmission() });
```

I want the `updateOrderSubmission` function to console log the value of the radio button that is selected.

```
   var updateOrderSubmission = function() {
     var orderSubmission = {
       area: $('#submit-initial-form').find('[name=area],[checked=checked]').this.val()
     }
     console.log(orderSubmission)
   };
```

The code above doesn't work. How do I grab the value of the selected radio button? I need to do `.find()` with two conditions (name and checked), not just one condition.

**UPDATE**

So why does `$('#submit-initial-form').find('[name=area][checked=checked]').val();` NOT work? It's saying "Take the `submit-initial-form` ID and find a child element with `name=area` and `checked=checked` and return its value.

Only `$('#submit-initial-form').find(':radio[name=area]:checked').val()` works. Why do you HAVE to specify that it's a radio button?

Comment: because `[checked=checked]` looks for an attribute called checked with value checked which is present only in the first radio box in your case... when you change the checked state of a radio button the attribute value is not updated... so using the attribute selector will always return the first element(in your case)

Comment: when you use the `:checked` selector it will search for the element whose checked property is set that element is filtered

Comment: Ohhhhh.... that's the kicker. When I select another radio button `checked=checked` does NOT change from the originally ticked radio button. Additonally, `checked=checked` also doesn't get ADDED to the newly ticked radio button. I don't understand why this would be the case though - the view in the browser changes. Wouldn't the underlying HTML code need to change as a result as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, you may need to use the [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector

```
var updateOrderSubmission = function () {
    var orderSubmission = {
        area: $('#submit-initial-form').find('input[name=area]:checked').val()
    }
    console.log(orderSubmission)
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MBQaS/)

Comment: @A.Wolff may be be the almighty might know :)

Comment: ^^ true ^^ don't understand. Its unbelievable.

Comment: +1: This one certainly works (many of the others don't): http://jsfiddle.net/9GNpv/2/

Comment: Can someone give me a quick rundown on this: When do you use square brackets ( ie. `[name=area1]` ), square brackets with parenthesis ( ie. `[name="area1"]` ), colons ( ie. `:checked` ), and no colons ( ie. `input` )?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
area: $('#submit-initial-form').find(':radio[name=area][checked]').val()
```

or:

```
area: $('#submit-initial-form').find(':radio[name=area]:checked').val()
```

Comment: `area: $('#submit-initial-form').find(':radio[name=area]:checked').val()` is the one that works.

Comment: Yes, the first one always returns the first `area` element. The second one works: http://jsfiddle.net/9GNpv/3/

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the game, (busy checking all the answers) but why did no-one remove the redundant `find`?

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9GNpv/5/

```
$('#submit-initial-form input[name=area]:checked' ).val()
```

*Which can be reduced to:*

```
$('#submit-initial-form [name=area]:checked' ).val()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9GNpv/7/ *but I prefer the selector to be a little more explicit myself*

### Update

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

- The brackets are attribute filters (max one per element type it appears).
- The `:` ones are the custom filters (you can extend jQuery with your own - see below).
- Not having anything implies an element type.

You could apply more than one attribute filter if you repeat the element type, but that gets a little weird:

### Extending custom selectors:

This is an example of adding a new custom selectors to jQuery :

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    focusable: function (el, index, selector) {
        return $(el).is('a, button, :input, [tabindex]');
    }
});
```

Which you can use like this:

```
var focusableElements = $(':focusable');
```

Comment: The `:` ones are specially defined? Is there a term for what these specially defined things are, or a list of which ones are specially defined? It would be useful to know which ones are special so I know when I can use `:` and when I can't. And why does `[name=area1]` do the same thing as `[name="area1"]`?

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny: Refer to the reference link provided: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ They have no specific name I know of, I just call them custom selectors (you can even extend jQuery to add your own)

Comment: @fuzzybabybunny: Added practical example of extending the custom selectors.

Answer (score 0):

If you add comma to the selector then it would be considered as a multiple selector

Try,

```
var updateOrderSubmission = function() {
  var orderSubmission = {
   area: $('#submit-initial-form').find('[name=area][checked=checked]').val();
  }
};
```

Comment: This does not work. When I tick another radio button the console log still says that area1 is checked.

Comment: Sorry, has anyone actually checked this answer? Multiple attribute selectors do not appear to work. This selector always returns the first name for the first condition http://jsfiddle.net/9GNpv/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#submit-initial-form').find(".track-order-change:input[type=radio]:checked" ).val();
```

Comment: @Manishankar, did you test that selector?

Comment: +1: This answer does work: http://jsfiddle.net/9GNpv/6/ because it qualifies the second filter. Can be reduced to `[name=area]:checked` though.

Answer (score 0):

You can find this way

```
var domIds = $('#week').find("[data-status=open][data-item-id=stand-out]")
$("#result").html(domIds.text());
```